# PHP extracting data from multidimensional array / JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm retrieving data from Wikipedia API in JSON format:

`{"batchcomplete":"","continue":{"gsroffset":2,"continue":"gsroffset||"},"query":{"pages":{"42068":{"pageid":42068,"ns":0,"title":"Freddie Mercury","index":2},"5119376":{"pageid":5119376,"ns":0,"title":"John F. Kennedy","index":1}}}}`

How can I get title data?

I've tried `strstr`, but it works only for 1 result (as you can see, there are two of them).

I've tried json_decode into array `$json = json_decode($url, true);`, but the array is multidimensional and I'm struggling to get the data out of it.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you should use `json_decode` and not use string methods.

This is how you can get access to the title of each page:

```
$data = json_decode($jsonData, true);
$pages = $data['query']['pages'] ?? [];

foreach ($pages as $page) {
    echo $page['title'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Robert! It works. I spent 2 hours, looking through every question here on StackOverflow and no one had as simple and conscise method as yours.

Comment: No problem! You should exercise it on a few examples to understand how accessing multidimensional arrays works, but basically once you know how to access 1-d arrays, you know how to access n-d arrays, you just chain the square bracket syntax, but be careful that sometimes a key may not be set.